# URL based HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: http, basic-authentication

A number of applications support the following method for passing authentication credentials to a server:

https://username:password@www.example.com

Among these applications are both wget and Firefox (but not IE).

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the ability to pass credentials via the URI an HTTP standard?
2. Does this method only work for HTTP Basic authentication or will it work for any authentication scheme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the ability to pass credentials via the URI an HTTP standard?

It is part of the [URI authority scheme](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#authority).

> Does this method only work for HTTP Basic authentication or will it work for any authentication scheme.

It is on the URL. It will work with HTTP/HTTPS. It will not work with things like forms authentication.